# How to keep session alive between two calls to a web service in a c# application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

This is quite straight forward.
I'm calling a web-service (.asmx, with session enabled) from a c# application.

I want each call to be with the same session key as the previous one (as opposed to creating a new session key each time).

Here's my (nothing-out-of-the-ordinary) code:

```
public string invokeMethod(string methodUrl)
{
 HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(methodUrl);
 req.Method = "GET";
 req.ContentLength = 0;
 var result = new StringBuilder();
 using (HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
 {
   StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());
   result.Append(sr.ReadToEnd());
 }
 return result.ToString();
}
```

Now I want to call it again, in the same session.

**Added:** Thanks to **Waleed**'s answer, I think I should be doing (after retrieving the session id) something like:
**Added once more:**  This is how it's done:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentSessionID))
{
  Cookie cookie = new Cookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", currentSessionID);
  cookie.Domain=myDomain;  //Will not work without this line!
  req.CookieContainer.Add(cookie);  
}
```

Thanks again.

Comment: as I pointed out Waleed's answer will not work since the session id will be invalid. You need to reuse TCP connection to keep the session alive and only in that case you will be able to use the session id.

Comment: @Aliostad: see my comment @Waleed's answer

Comment: Yes, sorry, I jsut dont know why I mixed the KeepAlive concept with the ASP.NET sessions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, I believe you'll need to get the session cookie from the response (the first time you call the web service) and add it to the request in the subsequent calls.

Edit:

Using CookieContainer is the correct way but be aware that it's [null by default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer.aspx) so you'll have to to assign a CookieContainer object to the property before making the request (see the example code in the MSDN's article).

As to the cookie name, the default name for ASP.NET session cookie is ASP.NET_SessionId, but the name can be different as it can be changed in web.config, or they might not be using ASP.NET sessions (their own implementation for example), so you'll have to check the cookies you get from the domain of that application (You can use an HTTP sniffer like Fiddler, or more easily if you're using FireFox or Chrome, you can check the names and contents of the cookies you get from that domain in the options dialog box).

Comment: Thanks for the input, I've got a few steps forward but stuck again, please refer to my edit.

Comment: Sorry for negative but had to do it. In the surface this looks good. But in reality the session id will be invalid when TCP connection is closed so the session id will be replaced with a new one by the server.

Comment: @Aliostad: I'm not sure if I got exactly what you meant, but it worked for me.

Comment: @Aliostad, actually the session id will not change if you send the session cookie to the application. The application will only create another session id if it doesn't find a session cookie in the request.

Comment: @Waleed I will be most surprised if that is the case. It will be a security breach in my view. Do you have a reference for this? But if it is the case, then well done for this level of depth of knowledge. I will check and get back to you.

Comment: Also this will not have the desired effect of keeping the session. if it creates the session id if does not exist. This will mean all the session data has been lost anyway.

Comment: @Aliostad, HTTP is stateless so TCP doesn't affect the application session (it's used for the connection with the server of course). Session expiration is time based in ASP.NET, so you only need to send a cookie that contains a valid session id (for a session that has not yet expired). Even if you send another session id or get another session id issued to you, you still can send an old session id as long as the session has not expired. Of course, this is assuming they use the default ASP.NET sessions, and don't have their own different implementation.

Comment: Just to add, you can also send the session id of an expired session (but of course the the session data will have already been lost). ASP.NET will just create a new session object for that id.

Comment: @Aliostad, it's ok mate, it's no big deal :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a good discussion of using ASP.NET session state with web services on MSDN here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480509.aspx

Answer (score 1):

From first call, look after `ASP.NET_SessionId` value in response, this is session Id by default.

Then add it to next call (see below):

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=899918