# SessionId changes while calling a method from a Webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two projects. One of them has a WebService(asmx) and the second one uses the WebService as a reference.

This is the WebMethod:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public int GetDocCount(CompressedData data)
{
    if (Session[Settings.cStrSessionUserLogin] == null)
    {
        return 0;   
    }
    string xmlString = EncoderUtil.Decompress(data);
    SortFilterSet sfs = (SortFilterSet)XmlUtil.Deserialize(typeof(SortFilterSet), xmlString);
    Session[Settings.cStrSessionSortFilterSet] = sfs;
    Session[Settings.cStrSessionOrderCodeList] = null;      

    return Database.GetOrderCount((List<RequestorInfo>)Session[Settings.cStrSessionRequestorList], sfs.FilterSet, sfs.SearchPattern);
}
```

When i create the client i have one sessionid, but whenever i call the WebMethod i see the SessionId changes inside the WebMethod(i can see that with Debug)

```
MyWebServiceSoapClient client = new MyWebServiceSoapClient();
int countDocs = client.GetDocCount(data);
```

Why am I seeing a new SessionId in the WebMethod, and how can I avoid this and get the original SessionId?

**EDIT :** Inside the WebMethod Session.Count is always 0

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to keep session alive between two calls to a web service in a c# application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862638/how-to-keep-session-alive-between-two-calls-to-a-web-service-in-a-c-sharp-applic)

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the WebService reference and then i inserted the MyWebServiceSoapClient.asmx and MyWebServiceSoapClient.cs in my project. Now i don't get the new SesseionId's anymore.