# Does SessionID change for each call to webservice?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, session

I don't understand the notion of session for webservices. In one hand you can allow session in DataAnnotation like that :

```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
```

In the other and you can configure the session state in IIS :
So I put Session State in process and set the delay for 20 minutes.

Then in my webservice I try to get the session ID like that :

```
   return HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID
```

I use a winform to get this information and call the webservice.

And the session ID Change at every call. I don't understand why, beaucoup SessionState is set to 20 minutes...

May I'm in wrong way ? Can you explain me ?

Is SessionID correspond to the Session State in IIS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be something that connects the request to a particular session. Usually a cookie is used for that. This cookie is sent along with the response, so the calling application must remember that cookie and send it along with the next request. Without cookie the request is handled as if it's a new session.

A browser handles this by default (unless specifically switched off), for an other application you need to do cookie management yourself. For this you need to use a single CookieContainer that will be shared among your requests.

See the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3862638/121309) in the answer by Marius for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking of a solution, but then I found this post :

[How to keep session alive between two calls to a web service in a c# application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862638/how-to-keep-session-alive-between-two-calls-to-a-web-service-in-a-c-sharp-applic)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your sessionID same througout users session life time you should add a global.asax file to your web project and implement Session_Start method.

Please check this link: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.sessionid.aspx